# Swift String omit/convert polish accents

Tags: swift, url

I have a following problem:
I am making an API request. With a city name f.e. 'Poznań" (containing some signs typical for some language), swift doesn't want to give me the result, but when I do the same request through Postman app it gives the result in a proper way. How can can I prevent swift from converting those 'strange' letters? 'city.name' is city name that I pass from the previous VC and googlePlaces API. Here is sample of a request and part of my code: 
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

```
private let kWeatherAPIURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%@&appid=%@"

let urlString = String(format: kWeatherAPIURL, city.name, weatherAPIKey)
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("address doesnt exist!")
        return
    }
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: here is my URLAddress:
 let urlString = String(format: kWeatherAPIURL, city.name, weatherAPIKey)
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("address doesnt exist!")
            return
        }

I just want swift to read polish, french signs etc. to allow me to make a proper API request. Warsaw, London work perfectly but city names with unusual letters doesn't

Comment: Please do include that snippet of code in your question, and all relevant code

Comment: Please include a sample input `urlString` to show in which part of the request the accented city name is

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use `URLComponents` rather than `String(format:)`. It would handle escaping (which you need in this case) in most usual cases.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove diacritics from a string or how to url encode a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am force unwrapping here for brevity:

```
let kWeatherAPIURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%@&appid=%@"
let weatherAPIKey = "YourWeatherAPIKey"
let cityName = "Poznań"


let cString = cityName.cString(using: .utf8)!
let utf8CityName = cityName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

let urlString = String(format: kWeatherAPIURL, utf8CityName, weatherAPIKey)
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

//https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pozna%C5%84&appid=YourWeatherAPIKey
```

A safe approach would be to use [URL components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents):

```
let weatherAPIKey = "YourWeatherAPIKey"
let cityName = "Poznań"


var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "api.openweathermap.org"
components.path = "/data/2.5/weather"
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: cityName),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: weatherAPIKey)
]

print(components.url!)  //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pozna%C5%84&appid=YourWeatherAPIKey
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Answer (score 1):

An example of using `URLComponents`.

Prepare a function like this:

```
func createWeatherAPIURL(cityName: String, apiKey: String) -> URL? {
    let kWeatherAPIURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"

    var urlCompo = URLComponents(string: kWeatherAPIURL)
    urlCompo?.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: cityName),
        URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: apiKey)
    ]
    return urlCompo?.url
}
```

And use it:

```
    guard let url = createWeatherAPIURL(cityName: city.name, apiKey: weatherAPIKey) else {
        print("address doesnt exist!")
        return
    }
```